# How do I resolve the error: "Expression type '()' is ambiguous without more context"?

Tags: ios, swift

I typed my code out and for some reason, I get this error:

> Expression type '()' is ambiguous without more context

This is my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ref.child("schedule").child("day0").observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
        var postData = [NSDictionary]()
        list = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)! //error here 
        print("\(list)")
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

If you want more code, ask me.

Comment: You have initialized the `list` variable elsewhere in your code, correct?

Comment: i made it a global variable, but when i change that i still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
                      mynamesArray = []

                       for child in snapshot.children {
                          mynamesArray.append((child as AnyObject).key)
                       }

                       print (mynamesArray)

                     })
```